# what is meaning of "on"

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am a Japanese web developer.

I am not good at English , but I want to be better.

Sometimes, I see function starts with "on" , like "onResize" , "onDrop".

What is this "on" meaning?

I thought this "on**" means like "when ** ( happened )".

So, I thought it would be better to say "onResized" , not "onResize".

Or "onWindowResized" , not "onWindowResize".

Can someone please tell me , what is the meaning of "on"?

---

Thank you so much for a lot of answer.

I read them all.

Well, what I thought is that if you say "onWindowResize" I feel like the window resizes them self by own.

But the one who resizes the window is us.

And window is something that is resized by us.

So I feel weird to hear "onWindowResize".

Well but I am bad at English , and my feeling of English should be wrong.

Comment: Well going by English language, in a broad sense, `onResize` would mean the start of the resize event, and `onResized` would mean after the event has ended.

Comment: `onResize` = when a resize *event* happens. Before the resize is completed.

Comment: ya you though is correct.Its called when the happen (its call event). `onResize` While doing the job on resize .`onResized` is means after finishing the job.same thing as windowresize. in simplest english resize is present dance and resized is past tense

Comment: @akao You can see my edited answer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's more of an English language or grammar 
or dictionary definition or semantics question than anything related to actual Coding issues. Not directly related to any tech  SE site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For no confusion, You can easily think `on` as it is being happening, not always the completion.

`onChange` for example, something is being changing(`event`) so we might add some `event-handler` for that event.

---

For your edited question, It doesn't matter that who resizes the window.

You can focus it to `event - event-handler` relation.

When someone (maybe your user) changes the window size using his/her mouse, you can add some `event-handler` like `alert("window is being resized")` to `onWindowResize` event which means window resizing is being happened.

Comment: Thank you so much. Hmmm , I see. 'onWindowResize event which means window resizing is being happened' is very new feeling for me. But I shouid be used to that imagination. Thank you.

Comment: I am sorry, I want to know one more thing. "onWindowResize" and "onResizeWindow" , which is better?

Answer (score 4):

It works like the English phrases "dead on arrival" or "cash on delivery". Arrival and delivery represent events in time, so in javascript it is like saying "take action on event", where the action is the associated function and the event is the javascript event.

Answer (score 2):

Using "on" before any function, its just a convention. As an example, in react most of the developers define their function with two ways -

1. handleResize
2. resizeHandler

I think, on indicates - this function is doing/did/will do something according to any event.

Like you want to remove a div when clicking a button, you can define this function like onRemove.

Answer (score 2):

When it say `on[Verb]` it mean when [Verb] happened or being happen: not always after happened.